# Is there a way to combine foreach loop

Tags: c#

I have 2 lists as follows:

```
valuesToMatch = ["someemail@something.com", "123-45-6789"]
regexValuesToMatchWith = ["^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9-]+\.(com|org|edu|)(\.[a-z]{2,3})?", "^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$"]
```

I want to match the email with email regex and SSN number with SSN regex. If both are true, then only I can add data, not otherwise.

```
public bool MatchRegex(Data data)
{
    var regexMatch = false;
    var valuesToMatch = GetValuesToMatch(data.values);
    var regexValuesToMatchWith = service.Validations(data.id);
    foreach (var toMatch in valuesToMatch)
    {
        foreach (var withRegex in regexValuesToMatchWith)
        {
            var r = new Regex(withRegex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            if (r.IsMatch(toMatch))
            {
                regexMatch = true;
            }
        }
    }

    if (regexMatch)
    {
        return dbContext.Add(data);
    }

    return false;
}
```

I have looked at approaches online but I am not sure if this is possible to achieve.

Comment: is above code gives u output or not?

Comment: Are the regexes and values expected to be in the same order, and have the same number of items?

Comment: @Richardissimo, Yes. First regex value shoud be for email and so on.

Comment: @ershoaib, It returns true or false

Comment: Then Nathalia's answer is what you need, now she has fixed the typo, and you have confirmed the assumptions she has made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe a `for` loop would be more suitable for what you're trying to achieve.

```
bool regexMatch = true;

for (int i = 0; i < withRegex.Length; i++)
{
        var r = new Regex(valuesToMatch[i], RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        if (!r.IsMatch(regexValuesToMatchWith[i]))
        {
            regexMatch = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The `foreach` loop will compare each value with both email and SSN regex, which is unnecessary. Besides that, if you set `regexMatch` to true like you're doing, it's going to be true even if one of the comparisons doesn't match.

I'm assuming `valuesToMatch` and `regexValuesToMatchWith` are always of the same size and with data in correct order, based on your example.

Comment: Typo `y`, and you need to make clear the assumptions this answer is making.